# After moving Wordpress to its own directory, login doesn't work

Tags: login, htaccess, directory

My site keeps getting hacked, so I decided to move WordPress to its own directory so that I can generate and use static pages in the main directory with Simply Static.

I am trying to move WordPress to its own directory, using “Method II” here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

[image: procedure start]

[image: htaccess]

And here where it doesn’t work.

The url goes to: https://subvariant.com/wordpress/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsubvariant.com%2Fwordpress%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

The css is not working, and using a correct login doesn’t do anything–it stays on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that plugin (and plugin support should be done on the plugin's support page, not here).

But my first thought is that you need to determine why your site keeps getting hacked. It would seem that you are not removing any hacked files from your site, and perhaps that's an issue that you should fix first.

Whenever I fix a hacked site for someone, I change all credentials (hosting, FTP, WP admin-level users), using strong passwords (and not shared). Then I reinstall everything (WP, themes, plugins) from WP Repository sources. Then I look at all settings of everything for things that don't belong there.  I also look at plugins that haven't been updated for a while. And any Child Themes (and their functions.php) for any code that shouldn't be there.

Then I look at all folders on the site for files that shouldn't be there. (Since you reinstalled everything at this point, sorting by reverse date helps, as everything that you reinstalled should have the same date. So looking for things that don't have the same date are helpful.)

I also look at the source code of generated pages, for anything that shouldn't be there. And at the Network tab in Developer Tools so I can find requests that shouldn't be there.

So, I think your first step should be to properly de-hack your site. Then you can contact the plugin support for 'Simply Static' - if that plugin is really needed.

Comment: Thank you for that rundown. However I've done all of that, so the hack is not there anymore. I have not installed Simply Static yet. This is the original database on a fresh Wordpress install.